# How does the transition from one page to another work in http://nptel.ac.in/course.php site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

after clicking on page 2 it shows the further results? where are these results stored before on how does this work? 
here it the website (http://nptel.ac.in/course.php)